# Can I chain a Knex Raw command?

Tags: knex.js

I'm using knex.raw to insert rows with Postgres ON CONFLICT... I want to insert multiple row like batchInsert.  How can I chain raw statements?  The TypeScript interface suggests you can't.

My current implementation uses a forEach + await (promise) which is obviously making remote many calls.

```
const data = [
  { ref : 'A', name : 'My A' },
  { ref : 'B', name : 'My B' },
  { ref : 'C', name : 'My C' }
];

await items.forEach(async (item) => {
    const insert = trx.table('myTable').insert({'ref': item.ref, 'name' : item.name}).toSQL();
    const onConflict = 'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT myTable_pkey DO NOTHING';
    await trx.raw(`${insert.sql} ${onConflict}`, insert.bindings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot chain raw queries... each raw is a single query. But what kind of query are you trying to achieve by chaining? Why you cannot just do:

```
const insert = trx.table('myTable').insert(items).toSQL();
const onConflict = 'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT myTable_pkey DO NOTHING';
await trx.raw(`${insert.sql} ${onConflict}`, insert.bindings);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a batchInsert but with 'ON CONFLICT' for each row inserted.  After doing some further research in the knex codebase it that appears that batchInsert is just a parallel async insert wrapped in a transaction not a single db call which is what I'm trying to achieve.  Theres lots of discussion around running multiple statements in a single call but looks like that support wont be coming anytime soon.

Comment: Do you know if that kind of query is even possible to do with postgresql? What are you trying exactly achieve by that? AFAIK the way I did here does on conflict for every row separately so in case of conflicting row that row is ignored and the rest are added.